Is McNemar's test appropriate for analyzing binary medical data in multiple setups?
I’m analyzing a dataset from patients with lymphedema. Each patient underwent the same examination under two conditions:

Without prior physiotherapy.
With physiotherapy immediately before the exam.

For each patient and each exam, I have x binary criteria (0 = normal result, 1 = pathological result). Here’s the analysis I’ve conducted

Per criterion: Constructed a 2x2 contingency table for each criterion and applied McNemar’s test to check if the proportion of pathological results differed between the two conditions.
Per patient: Aggregated all criteria for each patient into one contingency table and applied McNemar’s test again.
Globally: Combined all criteria and patients into a single contingency table and applied McNemar’s test.

My main question: Is McNemar’s test appropriate in all three cases, or are there alternative statistical tests that would be more suitable for a robust and comprehensive analysis of this type of data?
I’m particularly interested in methods that account for the dependence between criteria within patients or across the dataset. Any suggestions to improve my approach would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
Example data:
Each patient underwent two examinations under different conditions:
Without physiotherapy
With physiotherapy
Here’s an example of a contingency table summarizing the results for one criterion across patients:
|                        | With Physiotherapy: Positive(0) | With Physiotherapy: Negative(1) |
|------------------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| Without Physiotherapy: Positive(0) | 5                                 | 1                                 |
| Without Physiotherapy: Negative(1) | 2                                 | 8                                 |
In this table:

"Positive" indicates a normal result.
"Negative" indicates a pathological result.


Sorry but the table didn't look like this when I preview the answer. It is more like that but it was just an example the main concern is about the test. Thank you in advance

Welcome to cross validated. Check the number of backticks you have. There must be an errant one that’s rendering parts that look like code that aren’t.

Thank you for your advice and your welcoming

fixed it for you

Hmm, can't get the table right. Looks like it's: positive-positive: 5, positive-negative: 1, negative-positive: 2, negative-negative: 8
